# Python decorator for attribute and method?

Tags: python, methods, attributes, decorator, python-decorators

Is it possible to have a decorator that makes a method work like an attribute if values are assigned to it using `class.something = 2` and work like a method if it is called like `class.something(2, True)`?

## What I currently have

To be more concrete, I currently have the following

```
class attributeSetter(object):
   ''' Makes functions appear as attributes. Takes care of autologging.'''
   def __init__(self, func):
       self.func = func

   def __set__(self, obj, value):
       return self.func(obj, value)

   def __repr__(self):
       return repr(self.__getattribute__)
```

So with this class with a decorated method:

```
class myClass(object):
   @attributeSetter  # decorated!
   def myAttrib(self, value, add=False, subtract=False):
       if add:
           value += 2
       if subtract:
           value -= 2
       self.__dict__['myAttrib'] = value
```

I can do this:

```
instance = myClass()
instance.myAttrib = 2  # sets the value to 2
instance.myAttrib *= 4  # now 8
print instance.myAttrib  # 8
```

## What I want

But I want, in addition, to be able to do this:

```
instance.myAttrib(3, add=True)  # now 8 + 3 + 2 = 13
instance.myAttrib(0, subtact=True)  # now 13 + 0 - 2 = 11
print instance.myAttrib  # 11
```

My hunch is that I just have to add a **__call__** to the `attributeSetter` decorator like this:

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

but then it won't let me set values using the "=" syntax.

## Why?

I'm co-developing PsychoPy (a python module for stimulus delivery in psychphysics) and we want do to some processing when each stimulus parameter is set, hence the decorator to avoid setter/getter methods. We log each attribute change by default but in some cases, users want to disable logging of this particular setting with an extra log=False argument, or provide more arguments. Hence it would be nice in those cases if could just use the attribute like a function/method, which it really is in the first place.

Comment: I noticed a little on the late side that you expect `instance.myAttrib` to be both the managed value, **and** the callable `instance.myAttrib()`. You cannot have both, I am afraid. `instance.method_name` returns a bound method, which you can store in a variable and call later. The `()` in `instance.method_name()` is applied *after* the attribute has been looked up.

Comment: In other words, neither the class, nor the `__get__` method on a descriptor object will know what you are going to do with the returned attribute. That's entirely up to the `__call__`.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters! I've edited "class method". It's sad news but you've done a good job explaining why. I'll accept the answer later, depending on whether more answers are given in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to implement a [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) returning a callable; your decorator already provides a descriptor object, simply make it work when accessing as an attribute.

This can be as simple as turning around and binding the wrapped function (so you get a bound method):

```
class attributeSetter(object):
    ''' Makes functions appear as attributes. Takes care of autologging.'''
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        return self.func(obj, value)
```

**However**, this makes it incompatible with simply accessing the attribute! `instance.myAttrib` now returns a bound method! You cannot have it both ways here; methods are simply bound attributes (so attributes that passed through the descriptor protocol), that happen to be callable.

You could of course return a proxy object from `__get__`; one that implements a `__call__` method and otherwise tries to act as much as possible as the underlying managed instance attribute (what your function stored in `self.__dict__['myAttrib']`); but this path is fraught with problems as a proxy object can never truly *be* the underlying attribute value.