# Handle each class method call

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have the following class:

```
class Human:

    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0


human = Human()
print(human.age)  # 0
```

Want something like the following magic method. This magic method will give me an opportunity to handle the called variable before its returning.

```
class Human:

    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0

    def __variable_handler__(self, attribute_name):
        print(self, attribute_name) # Human instance, 'age'

human = Human()
print(human.age)  # 0
```

Could you help me and prompt the in Python how I can implement it?

Comment: do you mean like a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) but for an attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537646/python-decorator-for-attribute-and-method

Comment: You looking for `@property`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may implement by using `__getattribute__` method.

Code would be like:

```
class Human:

    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0

    def __getattribute__(self, attribute_name):
        print(self, attribute_name)
        try:
            return super(Human, self).__getattribute__(attribute_name)
        except AttributeError:
            return None
```

```
human = Human()
print(human.age)
```

Outputs would be:

```
<__main__.Human object at 0x11bfa0ef0> age
0
```